# Gold nucleus vs. M87 surface gravity

Tags: gravity, black-holes, nuclear-physics, event-horizon

I tried to solve this gedanken problem, but I get a nonsense solution (may be is non resoluble).

Take a gold nucleus. Nuclear radius is about $R=7.2 \:\rm fm$. Consider it a solid rigid sphere (I take that this can be indeed the problem, since we know nuclei are not solid spheres as we imagine). Calculate the surface gravity at the nuclear radius. Calculate the distance from the center of the nucleus where the surface gravity equals the surface gravity of the M87 black hole (for simplicity, I took 6 billion solar masses and not the more exact value). Take gold mass equals to 197 u.
That is, **where is the gravitational field (at what distance measured from the nuclear center) generated by the gold nucleus equals to the surface gravity on M87 black holes?**

The point is that whenever I calculate the distance:

1. If I suppose newtonian gravity proportional to $1/r^2$ (but it does not give a $r>R$ result). I get $10^{-20}$ meters (up to irrelevant numbers), which is smaller than the nuclear radius. But this can not be since inside the nucleus as solid sphere (I suppose nuclear density is not constant and that is why I cannot get a meaningless solution).
2. Considering the nucleus as solid sphere with constant density, I get $10^{-5}$ meters, what is nonsense since I wanted a $r<R$ size.

What is the real solution, if any?

To summarize:

1. Supposing $g$ proportional to $1/r^2$ in both the nucleus and M87 case, the distance where the surface gravity of the gold nucleus equals the M87 surface gravity equals about $10^{-20}$ meters.
2. Supposing $g$ proportional to $r$ AND the constant density, we get $10^{-5}$ meters.

Of course, I am suspecting (2) is not correct since, after all, nucleus have no constant density and black hole interiors can not be in principle linear in density. However, taking for sure (1) conflicts the fact nuclear size has a finite high density, I believe.

Comment: You've been here for a while - you should not need others to step in to make sure that your posts use correct mathematical formatting.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I am eager to edit properly my posts to be properly understood.

Comment: Good. Now make it "always" instead of "sometimes".

Comment: Gravity and quantum mechanics don't mix well. I guess your problem is the definition of "radius" of a nucleus. Wikipedia gives the "radius" of Au to be 114 pm and states that this is "empirical", probably based on interaction experiments.

Comment: @GyroGearloose 114 pm is the radius of a gold **atom**, not a gold nucleus. Using the rule-of-thumb $r=r_0A^{1/3}$ for $r_0=1.2$ fm and $A=197$, we get $r\approx7$ fm.

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake. Anyway, I strongly suspect the definition of *radius* is the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Nuclei are quantum mechanical entities, and have to be described by quantum mechanics , i.e. built up by protons and neutrons, which in turn are composites of quarks.

> where is the gravitational field (at what distance measured from the nuclear center) generated by the gold nucleus equals to the surface gravity on M87 black holes?

The mass of the nucleus is distributed within its radius in a quantum mechanical way, i.e in a probabilistic manner. There is no way to assume that the mass is concentrated in a smaller radius than the envelope of the nucleus as given by various models. The most appropriate would be the [liquid drop model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula#The_liquid_drop_model_and_its_analysis) where a radius of the nucleus can be estimated. The nucleons will be in a probability distribution within that radius.

So the gravitational field can be estimated using classical gravity up to outside the radius of the nucleus. For smaller distances it is a probability distribution, and one cannot concentrate it to small dimensions as you are imagining.

Comment: "The mass of the nucleus is distributed within its radius", if so, it should be rather irrelevant on exactly how it is distributed. I rather assume that due to quantum mechanics, part of the mass is *outside* what is considered the radius.

Comment: @GyroGearloose  No, it is within the radius, rather the radius is in effect  as the radius of the probability locus. What is relevant is that it is highly improbable to be concentrated into the small radius as imagined by the OP

Comment: That's right, nuclei are quantum entities, BUT, we are said that we can ignore quantum mechanics at the size of the nuclei or atoms, so in principle, as we remain out of the realm (it seems) of quantum gravity or heavy and tiny objects, newtonian (not even GR) should be able to get an answer for this...However, it seems we get bad results...Is it meaningful to calculate the surface gravity of a dense compact bunch of particles if we are NOT in Planck length/volume/area regime?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer, correct or not, is consistent with the fact that the gold or any other nucleus is, of course, far from being a black hole. The second answer must be incorrect.

Comment: My2cts...I doubt as well of the former, since, well...I expected to find out that the radius at which the surface gravity is equal to the M87 surface gravity were greater than the nuclei, otherwise I thought I would have effects due to the dense matter of the nucleus. However, as you see when you calculate it...That is not the case...The nucleus is very dense BUT it can not be "solid" nor even "liquid" as the drop model suggests...

Comment: Your last statement is a non sequitur.